# Redux gives error "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions, redux-middleware

I'm very new to redux. I tried my best to resolve this error in redux but it still gives me an error.
The error is message is:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
> actions.

Please help me resolve this.

The error points to the line after return. Here is my code:

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return{
        fetchState: (e) => dispatch(fetchState(e)),
        fetchCapital: (e) => dispatch(fetchCapital(e))
      }
    }
```

And `fetchState` is defined in my action.jsx

```
export const fetchState = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target)
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("hey")

        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/StatesByCountry/'+ e.target.value)
                .then(response => {
                    const stateData = response.data || '';
                    dispatch(changeState(stateData));
            })
            .catch( err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share your file where you create your store?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use async and await :

```
export const fetchState = async (e) =>{

await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/StatesByCountry/'+ e.target.value)
```

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Comment: Ca you suggest some change in mapDispatchToProps rather than fetchState?